# How to merge two if in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

My shell script looks like below.

```
#!/bin/bash
STR1="STRING1"
STR2="STRING2"

if [[ "sample string contains some value" == *"contains"* ]]; then
  if [ "$STR1" != "$STR2" ]; then
    echo "do something"
  fi
fi
```

How do I can merge two `if` line into single `if`?

My script searches for a substring in a string and compares the other two strings to do something.

Comment: See `&&` (a short circuiting Boolean expression)

Comment: The linked duplicate is for `||`, the "OR" counterpart to the `&&` "AND".